# How to set a cookie file from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chromium

I use the following Firefox extension to get cookies in Netscape HTTP Cookie File format.

I want to load the cookie in chrome browser from the command line by starting a new browser process. But I don't find an option to set a cookie input file.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

If this is possible, how can I do it?